# Не работает ajax запрос, код ошибки 0

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/file.php",
    data: {
        'a_name': 'success'
    },
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        alert("прибыли данные " + data.join("\n"));
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(' произошла ошибка: ' + textStatus + '.        сode=' + jqXHR.status);
    }
});
```

error отрабатывает и выдает:

> error. code=0

В чем может быть причина? Библиотека jquery подключена последняя.

Содержание file.php:

```
var_export($_POST); 
if (isset($_POST['a_name'])) echo "1!";
```

Comment: @prog2010, а в консоли нет ошибок?

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/users/9259/dazar 
я не уверен что правильно пользуюсь консолью - запустил firebug -перешел на консоль - выполнил отправку данных на странице - отобразилось

POST file.php 11ms jquery строка 9631
по этой строке находится  
// Do send the request
// This may raise an exception which is actually
// handled in jQuery.ajax (so no try/catch here)
xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );

это значит что на этой функции все стопорнулось?

Comment: @prog2010 а ответ во вкладке  сети есть ? 

хм, у вас data.join() а dataType html

Comment: @eicto, да вы правы, убрал join - теперь просто alert ("прибыли данные "+ data), 
но все равно отрабатывает error. На вкладке сети все файлы со статусом 200 ОК, file.php ответ пустой

Comment: @prog2010 оставьте в `file.php`  `<? var_dump($_POST); ?>`, что выдает?

Comment: разобрался. моя невнимательность. в упор не видел что из функции стояло return true -  соответственно выполнялся POST запрос из формы а не из функции обработчика с ajax запросом.